# SQL Update query to update one column from 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables table1 and table 2
Here is the select statement.

```
SELECT table1_column1, table1_column2, table1_column3, table2_column1,
        table2_column2, table2_column3
FROM table1
   , table2
WHERE table1_column1 = table2_column1
  AND table1_column2 = 'A'
  AND table1_column3 <> table2_column3
```

I get results where table1_column3 and table2_column3 have different values. which is correct.

I want to update and replace all of table2_column3 values with table1_column3
my update sql statement gives me ORA-00936: missing expression error.

Comment: So what is your `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: What do you mean by "update **all** of table2_column3 values"? The query is only for rows where `table1_column2 = 'A'` - will there still be at least one row in `table1` corresponding to **each** row in `table2`?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you must update (or insert into) a table based on values from another table, consider using the `merge` statement instead of `update/insert`:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

In your case, you seem to be trying to do this:

```
merge into table2 t2
  using table1 t1
    on (t1.column1 = t2.column1 and t1.column2 = 'A')
when matched then update set column3 = t1.column3
  where column3 != t1.column3
;
```

If instead you want to do this with an `update` statement, this may help:

[Update with joins](https://web.archive.org/web/20170915123941/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/8061/update-with-joins)